# Components not being rendered in webpack production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-production

So the thing is that everything works as expected with *webpack-dev-server*.

But when I manually open **index.html** after `npm run build`, I see only the ***header*** component being rendered and the rest, which is to be rendered after fetching data, is blank. There's no error in the console.

The *un-rendered* components are the `Route`s. Well I'm using `Route`s for the first time, and after searching a lot ***all I've come to understand is that I should use `historyApiFallback` and `publicPath` in *webpack.config.js****.

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
```

But the result is the same. I have no idea how it works different for development and production. I also want a little bit explanation of the fix that you may provide!

**Please let me know the cause and the fix as well!**

Link to project- https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-countries-api-1ibwp?file=/src/index.js:138-154

Comment: I see things work properly in your codesanbox. What is your problem?

Comment: @tmhao2005 the problem is that opening local files from the build folder doesn't work. Please read the question again!

Comment: I meant I tried with mode production mate but nothing weird gets happened

Comment: @tmhao2005 oh I see, it seems to work on *dev-server with production mode* too. But not with the files in *build* folder. I don't understand this!

Comment: I also tried to build locally then serve the built files but no luck:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try serving your build folder with a package like `serve` https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

Create a serve.json with the similar following contents for accessing sub-routes directly.

```js
{
  "public": "build",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/*",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```